# Nestjs exits with "killed" on EC2

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-ec2, nestjs

[image: exits with killed]My app exits with the message "killed" without any other reason or stack trace.
PS: It runs well locally. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered the problem was memory...

The server didn't have enough memory to start the nestjs process.